# javascript regex - extract number from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given "1/2009 stay longer" or "34/1874 got to go", how can I get the digit right after the "/" using regex.
`'1/2009'.match(/\d+\/(\d)\d\d\d/g)[0]` is returning `1/2009` which is not what I want.  thx

Comment: Try `[1]` instead of `[0]`

Comment: Unclear what kind of help you need. I.e. which part of [match - return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) did not explain meaning of the result for you?

Comment: Do you want `2` from `1/2009` or `2009`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your RegEx works, if you want single digit right after `/`**

Your regex `\d+\/(\d)\d\d\d` will match digits `/` then four digits and add first digit after slash in captured group.
Note that 0th captured group will contain complete matched string. `g` flag is not necessary as there is only one instance of numbers in that pattern.

You can use this regex, but use first index to get the digit right after slash.

```
'1/2009'.match(/\d+\/(\d)\d\d\d/g)[1]
                                   ^  : Get me the value from first captured group.
```

And this regex can be optimized to below

```
.match(/\/(\d)/)[1]
```

This will match the number followed by `/`. And use the first captured group to extract the number.

```html
<input type="text" onblur="console.log(this.value.match(/\/(\d)/)[1])" />
```

---

**To get all digits after `/`**

Just add `+` quantifier to `\d` in the captured group.

```
.match(/\/(\d+)/)[1]
```

Comment: I'm confused what exactly OP wants. So added both the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var string = "1/2009 stay longer";
console.log(string.match(/\/(\d+)/)[1]);
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits. If you're only interested in capturing the digit right after `/`, use `string.match(/\/(\d)/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec method of regExp object also:

```js
console.log(/\d+\/(\d).*/.exec('1/2009')[1]);
```